# how to get a relationship between two nodes in graph-database using cypher query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I want to get a relationship between two nodes ?

if there is a relation `node(1) [:knows] node(2)`
how do i get the relationship by using cypher query ?

```
START r=node(196), s=node(198) MATCH r-[rel:knows]->s RETURN TYPE(rel)
```

this gives what I want.

But since there could be different relationships between two node for example

```
node1 -[:knows]->node2 
node1 -[:friendrequest]->node 12
```

basically, i want to send nodes to the query and return whether relation is knows or friendrequest. thanks!

thanks!

Answer (score 4):

try

```
start n1=node(1) , n2=node(2)  match n1-[r]->n2 return r
```

Comment: or return type(r) if you are only interested in the type.

Comment: You can also limit the relationships types if you only want those two:
`[r:KNOWS|FRIENDREQUEST]`

Answer (score 3):

Aside from @Joerg's answer, consider that you *only* want the **knows** relationship, so you'd do something like this, otherwise you'd end up potentially returning multiple relationship nodes between `n1` and `n2`:

```
start n1 = node(1), n2 = node(2)
match n1-[r:knows]->n2
return r;
```

Comment: Hi,

I more like want to get knows relationship through query. 
I want to get result as knows from the query.

There is two nodes node1 and node2 and there could be various relationship between them like knows, friendsrequest.
I basically want to get the relation that exists between them. Thanks

Comment: Sorry but I don't know what else you're asking, as the answer I provided you with gives you *the relationship that exists between them,* as you asked. The relationship type is **knows** and the query I provided returns the variable *r* containing the relationship node between n1 and n2.

Comment: HI,

START r=node(196), s=node(198) 
MATCH r-[rel:knows]->s
RETURN TYPE(rel) 

this gives what I want. But since there could be different relationships between two node for example
node1 -[:knows]->node2
node1 -[:friendrequest]->node 12

basically, i want to send nodes to the query and return whether relation is knows or friendrequest. thanks!

Comment: Your original question asks specifically how to retrieve the **knows** relationship. If you want *any* relationship between the two nodes, then look at Joerg's answer, as he gave that to you. Please refer to the Neo4j [Learning portal](http://www.neo4j.org/learn) for more info about Cypher.

Comment: you can also use (r)-[rel:knows|friendrequest]->(s) for multiple rels, but if you don't want to limit the type go with Joergs answer.